# How exactly does a Max 2 Sat reduce to a 3 Sat?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard, satisfiability, decision-problem

I've been reading [this](http://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/williams-max2sat-encyc.pdf) article which tries and explains how the max 2 sat problem is essentially a 3-sat problem and is NP-hard. 
However, if you see the article, I'm *not able to understand why*, after `ci` is satisfied, 7 out of 10 clauses are satisfied and if it is not satisfied, the 6 out of 10 clauses are satisfied.

Can someone explain to me in simple terms, and demystify what exactly the article wants to convey? Essentially, I have come to know that a max-2-sat problem is the same as a 3 sat problem. The question is I'm not able to understand why.

More formally, I wish to solve this problem:

> Consider the problem MAX2SAT described as follows.
>   Given a 2-CNF (Conjunctive Normal Form) Boolean expression  (with m
>   clauses, n variables) and an integer k, Decide if there is an
>   assignment satisfying at least ‘k’ of the total clauses? Compute the
>   complexity class (P or NP or NP Complete) of the MAX2SAT with
>   justification.

Comment: "Can someone explain to me in simple terms" -- there are no shortcuts to complexity theory. Get [your basics straight](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/845/98), then try again.

Comment: By 'simple terms' I meant getting to realize it correctly. That's it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52473/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633005/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: There are accepted answers at both places so I don't think this matters eitherways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the lecture note has abused the symbol $c_i$. You should check the [original paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0304397576900591/1-s2.0-0304397576900591-main.pdf?_tid=7f0cd624-c743-11e5-af3b-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1454153021_c2a5ed0b65c2f6b3a003747e6166f60a).

---

Replacing each clause $C_i = (a_i \lor b_i \lor c_i)$ of 3CNF by the collection of 2CNF clauses:

$$(a_i), (b_i), (c_i), (d_i), (\bar{a_i} \lor \bar{b_i}), (\bar{a_i} \lor \bar{c_i}), (\bar{b_i} \lor \bar{c_i}), (a_i \lor \bar{d_i}), (b_i \lor \bar{d_i}), (c_i \lor \bar{d_i})$$

where $d_i$ is a new variable.

---

> Theorem: If an assignment $\alpha$ satisfies $C_i$, then exactly seven of the ten clauses in the 2-CNF collection can be satisfied.

***Proof:*** $\alpha$ satisfies $C_i$, then either one, two, or three of $a_i, b_i, c_i$ must be `true`. In all cases, there is a truth setting for $d_i$ causing exactly seven of the clauses to be satisfied. For example, suppose $a_i = \top, b_i = c_i = \bot$, then $d_i = \bot$ causes 7 clauses to be satisfied.

> Theorem: If an assignment $\alpha$ does not satisfy $C_i$, then exactly six of the ten clauses can be satisfied.

***Proof:*** $\alpha$ does not satisfy $C_i$, then $a_i = b_i = c_i = \bot$. In this case, if $d_i = \top$, 4 clauses are satisfied; if $d_i = \bot$, then 6 clauses are satisfied.

Comment: "di" is a new variable. Cool but is a 3 sat problem, we only have a,b,c (3 variables basically) correct? What EXACTLY is di?

Comment: @bholagabbar 3 means "each clause contains at most three literals". No limitation to the number of variables used in a formula. Note that $(d_i)$ means a single 2CNF clause.

Comment: Ok..and how do we finally conclude that this is NP? I mean what justification do we give formally?

Comment: @bholagabbar NP or NP-hard? For NP, you prove that you can verify whether an assignment of an Max-2CNF formula is a valid one in polynomial time. This is an easy part. For NP-hard, you can set $k = 7m/10$ combine the two theorems together and conclude that (in the lecture note): "If $F$ of 3CNF is satisfiable then there is an assignment satisfying 7/10 of the clauses in $F′$ of 2CNF, and if $F$ is not satisfiable then no assignment satisfies 7/10 of the clauses in $F'$".